# Select a control by custom property

Tags: c#, linq, for-loop, foreach

I've been trying for a while but I'd like to modify a specific control's `value` without looping through all controls to check if a textbox's `id` property matches a correct value.

Currently this is the code I have but I thought perhaps using LINQ it's more efficient;

```
for (int i = 0; i < protectMaxPlayers; i++)
{
    // Update the protect time.
        protect.setProtectTime(i, protect.getProtectTime(i) - 1);

        // Set the progressbar.
        foreach (ProtectProgressBar pb in pnlProtect.Controls.OfType<ProtectProgressBar>())
        {
            if (pb.Id == i)
                    pb.Value = protect.getProtectTime(i);
                }
        }
}
```

This loops through ALL the progressbars in order to find the right one.
Is this possible to get shorter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**LINQ will iterate over whole collection of `ProgressBar`s** as well, so it's not any better than your current solution.

You should consider preparing `Dictionary<string, ProtectProgressBar>` and using it to find the correct one using it's ID:

```
var bars = pnlProtect.Controls.OfType<ProtectProgressBar>().ToDictionary(c => c.Id, c => c);

for (int i = 0; i < protectMaxPlayers; i++)
{
    // Update the protect time.
    protect.setProtectTime(i, protect.getProtectTime(i) - 1);

    ProtectProgressBar bar;
    if(bars.TryGetValue(i, out bar))
    {
        bar.Value = protect.getProtectTime(i);
    }
}
```

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` lookup is done in *O(1)* time, so it should be better then you current solution.

Answer (score 0):

to accomplish this task, you must:

Import Linq namespace above.

```
import System.Linq;
```

Then use the code like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < protectMaxPlayers; i++)
{
    // Update the protect time.
    protect.setProtectTime(i, protect.getProtectTime(i) - 1);

    // Set the progressbar.
    ProtectProgressBar pb = pnlProtect.Controls.OfType<ProtectProgressBar>().ToList().Find(k => k.ID == i.ToString());

    // check if it was found
    if (pb != null)
    {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Regards, Wiliam.

Comment: Both `Find()` and `ToList()` iterate over source collection.